# 2.1 Amplifier bass output resistance is getting fried

Tags: amplifier

[image]
I have made an amplifier for the 2.1 sound system. The bass output resistance (10 ohm) in the amplifier is getting fried every time. My Speaker rating is 4 ohm 25 Watts.

Can you please help me with the output resistance.

[image]

Comment: *Can you please help me with the output resistance.* Nope because 1) repair questions are off-topic 2) your question **seriously** lacks in information, there should at least be a schematic.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sure i will add the schematic.

Comment: You should specify the values of your voltage sources (VDD_X and V+) as well as the resistor's power rating. Are you talking about R20, R11, or both?

Comment: I am talking about R20 only. And the value is 1/4 w 5 % 10 Ohm. My power source is 12-0-12 3amp. I have added the circuit diagram.

Comment: Can you post the layout? Where are the decoupling caps?

Answer (score 4):

It's the output snubber, so there are only 2 ways to burn it:

- either the cap which is in series somehow has an internal short (check with multimeter)
- or the amp is oscillating at HF so enough current goes through the cap to burn the resistor (check output with oscilloscope).

The conspicuous absence of any supply decoupling capacitors hint towards the second hypothesis. Please post layout. Most likely adding a few caps in the right spots will fix your problem.

**EDIT**

The wiring of POT2 is suspicious...

Besides the missing decoupling caps... where is the ground? I mean, there are positive and negative supplies, but the ground of the amp should be connected to the supply ground!...

Also, the layout is very convoluted, long thin traces even on the high current output and supplies, and the routing of ground is pretty bad, this will cause problems... also feedback components are very far from the amps... so I don't really know where to put the decoupling caps!